# Passing uint32_t array to Python using Python.h

Tags: python, c, stdint

I am trying to construct a module for python in C. The module has several lines and methods, but one of the most important is to pass, **efficiently**, the integer representation of the concatenation of a uint32_t array to python. For example, from code below

```
{
    uint32_t state[3] = {0x00000300, 0x00001100, 0x00022200}
    char charstate[12];
    memcpy(charstate, state, 12);
    return Py_BuildValue("s#", charstate, 12);
}
```

I expect in python the integer representation of the concatenation of that hex elements that is 0x000003000000110000022200 = 14167099467300633453056. As you can see I tried to use 's#', but without success. Could you give me an advice, please?

Comment: Do you mean `char charstate[12];`? `*charstate[12]` means a list of strings.

Comment: @rickimaru I correct it, thanks

Comment: `I expect in python the integer representation` What about endianess? From documentation of `Py_BuildValue` I see `s#` converts a C string. The first byte of `charstate` is `0x00` (either endianess way) so it's an empty string...

Comment: @KamilCuk for example for 0x000003000000110000022200 I expect 14167099467300633453056

Comment: What do you mean "for example"? `0x000003000000110000022200` is a number, not a string. `s#` takes a string. And a number equal to `state[0] << 32 | state[1] << 16 | state[2]` is _not_ equal to `memcpy` it, because most probably you are little endian..

Comment: i know, this is beacause I am asking about an efficient way to pass state to python. I expect in python a integer, in the example 14167099467300633453056. I used https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html to convert (that is exactly I need).

Comment: `in python a integer` Then why do you convert a `s#` string?..

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks you by attention. Understand what do you think is the correct type, if my integer is a "big" integer?

Answer (score 2):

> Passing uint32_t array to Python using Python.h

I would just do an array, as you have in C.

```
uint32_t state[3] = {0x00000300, 0x00001100, 0x00022200}
return Py_BuildValue("[k,k,k]", 
       (unsigned long)state[0],
       (unsigned long)state[1],
       (unsigned long)state[2]);
```

`unsigned long` is a type wide enough to store `uint32_t`.

> what do you think is the correct type, if my integer is a "big" integer?

If the value has more then 64-bits, there is no "correct" type. Is so, move the calculations to python side.

If you want a single value of `14167099467300633453056` on python side, then the widest available type in C can't fit it - `unsigned long long` has (at least) 64-bits, while the value is expected to have 96 bits. I suggest either to:

- to shift by 32 to the right or multiply by 2^32 the resulting values from the above code on python side, as python supports arbitrary number ranges, or
- convert the 3 values to it's string representation and convert that C-string to python string

```
char buffer[200];
int len = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 
     "%16"PRIx32"%016"PRIx32"%016"PRIx32,
     state[0], state[1], state[2]);
Py_BuildValue("#s", buffer, len);
```

and then convert the resulting value to number on python side, which would be analogous to `int("3000000110000022200", 16)` in python.

> I expect in python the integer representation of the concatenation of that hex elements that is 0x000003000000110000022200

After `memcpy` on a *little endian* system the content of `charstate` would be:

```
char charstate[12] = {
    0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x22, 0x02, 0x00 };
```

which on call to `Py_BuildValue("s#", charstate` to a python *string*, that would look like:

```
ret="\00\03\00\00\00\x11\00\00\00\x22\x02\00"
# len(ret)=12 - 12 bytes!
```

then you would have to convert each byte by byte to an integer and shift the result on each byte by 8 (or multiply by 2^8) to some accumulator to get the resulting value.

Comment: I tried        char charstate[12] = { 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x22, 0x02, 0x00 }; return Py_BuildValue("s#", charstate); But after python print I do not see something similar to \00\03\00\00\00\x11\00\00\00\x22\x02\00